# RestClient sends null data from winphone 8 to Wcf rest service

Tags: windows-phone-8, wcf-rest, restsharp

```
string URL="https://sampleservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/WinPhoneService/"  

RestClient client = new RestClient(URL);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("getkpimeasuredata", Method.POST);
KpiDomainData kpidata = new KpiDomainData();
kpidata.KPIId = 1006;
kpidata.ScorecardId = 3;
kpidata.EngineeringOrgId = 11;
kpidata.DataValuetypeId = 1;
kpidata.CumulativeMonth = 463;
kpidata.BusinessOrgId = 1;

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kpidata);

json = "{\"kpidata\" : " + json + "}";

request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

ObservableCollection<KpiMeasureData> kpiDetailsList = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<ObservableCollection<KpiMeasureData>>(request);

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                    {
                       if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                       {

                       }
                  });
```

When I debugged the wcf service code i came to know that the json data sent to `getkpimeasuredata` webmethod is null, I mean all the property values of the composite type were null even though I'm passing the data with values

And the Restcall works when I use Webclient instead of Restclient. But I need to use Restclient only. Please help.

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix to this problem?

Comment: Noo its not fixed yet!!